# Trying to do a simple array of structure c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Weather
{
  string month[12];
  double rainfall;
  double hitemp;
  double lotemp;
};

int main()
{
  Weather month[12] = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Decemeber"};

  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    cout << "month rainfall" << month[i] << endl;
    cin >> month[i].rainfall;
  }

  cout << month[3].rainfall;
}
```

Really new to c++ using GDB on my home desktop i use codeblocks in class though. Attempting to do an assignment involving storing data on weather for each month. I currently am running into this error. Should i use pointers ? or can you not use a pre-filled array and ill have to ask the user for the month?

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:25:34: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘Weather’)
         cout << "month rainfall" << month[i]<< endl;
```

Edit: i apologize i wasn't clear about my intention. I was attempting to have month[12] be all the months and then store the rainfall, highest temp and lowest temp, month by month by indexing through the array. Is it possible for each element in the array to be given a structure? Will i have to assign each months data individually? I apologize im not too well versed in the terminology.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use pointers. And the error has absolutely nothing to do whatsoever with "using a prefilled array". Pop quiz: what is "month[i]"? What type is this expression? (hint: it's not a `std::string` with the name of the month) How do you expect your computer to know what to do with `month[i]` and `cout`?

Comment: month[i] is an array with "i" being the index. I thought since the array is full of strings id be string month[12] 12 being the size. "Cout" is print in c++ i have "using namespace std;" so i don't have to manually type std::.

Comment: No, the `month` array isn't "full of strings". It's full of `Weather` objects. Which are not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out already, you have a couple initialization issues.  You're also leaving a lot of your structure's data unset.

I haven't touched on the second issue, but this fixes the first while staying strictly within the bounds you defined (ie an array of a simple structure):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Weather
{
    string month;
    double rainfall;
    double hitemp;
    double lotemp;
};

int main()
{
    string monthName[12] = { "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Decemeber" };
    Weather month[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Rainfall for " << monthName[i] << endl;
        month[i].month = monthName[i];
        cin >> month[i].rainfall;
        month[i].hitemp = month[i].lotemp = 0;
    }

    int outMonths[3] = { 3, 7, 11 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << month[outMonths[i]].month << " " << month[outMonths[i]].rainfall << endl; // Outputs: April, August, & December
    }
```

Personally, I'd go another step and add a constructor, maybe even use std::array just because. :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

struct Weather
{
    string month;
    double rainfall;
    double hitemp;
    double lotemp;

    Weather() {
        month = "";
        rainfall = hitemp = lotemp = 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string monthName[12] = { "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Decemeber" };
    array<Weather, 12> month;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Rainfall for " << monthName[i] << endl;
        month[i].month = monthName[i];
        cin >> month[i].rainfall;
    }

    int outMonths[3] = { 1, 6, 11 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << month[outMonths[i]].month << " " << month[outMonths[i]].rainfall << endl; // Outputs: February, July, & December
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your initialization is incorrect

```
Weather month[12] = {"January", "Febuary", "March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","Decemeber"};
```

You have declared an array named month which can store 12 `Weather` structures. I doubt this was your intention.
On the contrary you intended to initialize the `month` member of the `Weather` struct

Coming to the actual error you are seeing

```
cout << "month rainfall" << month[i]<< endl;
```

The compiler thinks you are trying to output the entire structure because `month[i]` refers to the ith element in the array of structures you've declared.

What you should be doing is something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Weather
{
    std::string month;
    double rainfall;
    double hitemp;
    double lotemp;

};


int main()
{       

        Weather yearlyweather[12];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> yearlyweather[i].month;
            std::cin >> yearlyweather[i].rainfall;
            std::cin >> yearlyweather[i].hitemp;
            std::cin >> yearlyweather[i].lotemp;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            std::cout << yearlyweather[i].month << "\n" << yearlyweather[i].rainfall << "\n" << yearlyweather[i].hitemp << "\n" << yearlyweather[i].lotemp;
        }


        return 0;


}
```

Comment: careless error. i just reused the same structure of the OP. fixed it now.

Comment: i've just extended what the OP has written and it is functional enough to demonstrate the reason for the error. Your comments are inconsequential given the context of the question

Comment: And how are you sure about the OP's intention? Are you able to provide some literature as to why an elaborated type specifier is bad

Comment: The goal was to cycle through the array of months and input the data for the structure. Is that possible?

Comment: @MugfaceTGE you then need a structure which can be used for any month

Comment: @uneven_mark i'll have a read but the use of elaborated type specifiers still comes down to programmer skill. Using it incorrectly could pollute the namespace not otherwise

Comment: @pcodex ok so i remove the month string from my structure. Will i be assigning each month manually (month[0] = January, month[1] = feb,etc) then month[i].rainfall will work?

Comment: not really. you could still have a month name in the structure. I'll edit my answer. have a look

Comment: This works perfectly only thing is i don't really want the user to input the month. I manually assigned the month to yearlyweather.month[etc]. 

When i tried "yearlyweather.month[12] = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", etc};" i got an error any idea why. Just a random question i'm just curious you've been very helpful thank you.

Comment: @MugfaceTGE array assignment has to be done at the specified index. So yearlyweather[0].month = "Jan"  and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your array is the problem. C++ thinks you are trying to print out a `struct Weather`.
You've made an array `Weather months[12]` consisting of 12 `Weather` structs. You then index that array, `months[i]`, but C++ does not know how to print a `Weather`.
Instead you need to access, say, the `month` attribute on the `Weather`.

```
Weather months[12];
months[0].month = "January";
// ETC

// To access the month value
months[i].month;
```

I also don't believe you'd want there to be a string array inside the weather struct.
Perhaps :

```
struct Weather {
    string month;
};
```

Comment: Why January is in second array element? :)

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat Haha, oops.

Comment: It seems more like OP doesn't want `months` to be of type array to `Weather` at all. They are never initializing all the fields in the question's code. They probably just want `std::string months[12] = ...`. `Weather` does not seem to need `month` at all.

Comment: @uneven_mark perhaps. It seemed to be a bit ambiguous as to the intent. Hopefully this helps OP sort out either way.

Comment: The goal was to cycle through the array of months and put in the structure data. Will i have to manually set each subscript of the array like your said? "months[0].month = "January";

Comment: @MugfaceTGE As you said this was for a class I was trying to refrain from writing the whole thing, like others seemed to have.  
As they've shown, you could use for loops to accomplish that.